# How can I kill a running script via script in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In Google App Script I have a script running but sometimes I manually start another script which I then want to interrupt the running script. How to I stop a running script via manually triggered script?

Answer (score 0):

To stop a running Google Apps Script from another script, you can use a shared flag stored in a place accessible by both scripts, such as Google Sheets or Script/Document/User Properties. This flag acts as a signal for the running script to terminate its process. Here's a basic approach:

1. **Setup a Flag:** Use a Google Sheet or Script/User Properties to store a flag.
2. **Check Flag in the main part of the script:** Periodically check the flag in your main script.
3. **Change Flag from another function:** Modify the flag, signaling the main script to stop. You can trigger this stop function in several different ways:

   1. Run the function from the main script via IDE or attach it to a button or custom menu (if it this script attached to a document or spreadsheet).
   2. Publish the main script as a library and add it to another script.  Then you can call the interrupt function from there like this:

   ```js
   function stopMainScript() {
     // `MainScript` is the name of the library
     MainScript.stopMainScript()
   }
   ```

   3. Publish the main script as a web app and use HTTP requests from another script to trigger it.

### Code

```js
function mainScript() {
  // Resetting the stopFlag at the begging of the run,
  // assuming that it should not be cancelled manually.
  resetStopFlag();

  while (true) {
    // Your script's main logic

    if (checkStopFlag()) {
      console.log('Stopping script');
      break;
    }
  }
}

function checkStopFlag() {
  const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const flag = scriptProperties.getProperty('stopFlag');
  return flag === 'true';
}

function resetStopFlag() {
  const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('stopFlag', 'false');
}

function stopMainScript() {
  const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('stopFlag', 'true');
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't mix a service script (I think) and a script that is run manually.  I'd add a timer to the check loop and add the stop method inside script 1.  Add script 1's project as a library to the manual script and call the stop method directly with projectName.stopMainScript().

Comment: @NathanChampion thanks, great idea.  Edited the response to include your suggestion.